# How to execute a apply_async task in a delayed task

Tags: python, celery

I want to execute a apply_aysnc task in a delayed task. But I get a error 'function' object has no attribute 'apply_async'.

tasks.py

```
from celery import task


def Test(func, delay_seconds):
    TaskA.apply_async((func, delay_seconds), countdown=1)

@task
def TaskA(func, delay_seconds):
    result = xxx
    if result:
        func.apply_async(countdown=delay_seconds)

def TaskB():
   xxx


Test.apply_async((TaskB, 600,), countdown=60)
```

I found that celery can execute 'Test' function. Then I want to execute func when result is True in TaskA, but it raise a exception when I try to 'apply_aysnc' TaskB. How to make func as a 'Task' object? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this question by myself

Use

```
task(func).apply_async(countdown=delay_seconds)
```

where task() will return a celery Proxy, instead of

```
func.apply_async(countdown=delay_seconds)
```